# How to test a function with functional test?

Tags: python, pytest

I want to perform a functional test, but the purpose of this test is to check the result of another function - `need_to_test`, it should not be a module test, I want to make sure that when starting `test_func`, another function, namely `need_to_test`, returns the result I need.

```
class Need_test_func:
    def need_to_test(self):
        return 'Red'

    def start_another_funk(self):
        return self.need_to_test() + ' Green'

    def test_func(self):
        self.start_another_funk()
        return
```

```
def test_check():
    need_test_func = Need_test_func()
    color = 'Red'
    
    assert next(need_test_func().test_func()) == 'Red Green'
```

my task is to write a functional test i.e. start working with the Need_test_func class from the test_func function and make sure that it works properly but I can't do a unit test and just check if need_to_test returns the right color I need to start with test_func and make sure that during the operation of this function, need_to_test is launched and returns the value I need
How i can do this?

Comment: What's your question/actual problem?

Comment: Inside `test_func()`, check that the result of `self.start_another_funk()` is equal to 'Red Green'.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: I don't know how to implement the test to make the statement that need_to_test returned Red while running test_func

Comment: generally i want to do something like `assert next(Need_test_func().test_func()) == 'Red Green'`

Comment: Are you writing a test for `need_to_test()` or one for `test_func()`?

Comment: Does the return value of `need_to_test()` affect the result of `test_func()`? If so, you should [edit] your question to include that behavior in your code example.

Comment: If it has no effect on behaviour, you can't test it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make sure that when starting test_func, another function, namely need_to_test, returns the result I need.

It sounds like you need a mock function that returns a specific value for the test. Then you can patch that function. In this particular situation, you can just assign the function on the object to whatever you want. For example:

```
def test_check():
    need_test_func = Need_test_func()
    def mock_func(self):
        return 'Blue'

    need_test_func.need_to_test = mock_func
    result = need_test_func.test_func()
```

Then you can assert the result of `test_func()`. In the current version of your question, `test_func()` isn't affected by `need_to_test()`, so I don't know what this assert would be. I assume this is a simplified version of a more complex project you are working on. I'll leave the assert as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: yes you are right I am working on a more complex project and decided to simplify it, my task is to write a functional test i.e. start working with the Need_test_func class from the test_func function and make sure that it works properly but I can't do a unit test and just check if need_to_test returns the right color I need to start with test_func and make sure that during the operation of this function, need_to_test is launched and returns the value I need

Comment: maybe I didn't ask my question correctly?

Comment: @self If this were my project, I would write both a unit test for `need_to_test()` and a functional test for `test_func()`. The functional test should be designed only with the input and output (including side effects) of `test_func()` in mind. It shouldn't be concerned about how `test_func()` is implemented. Just call `test_func()` and assert that the results are what you expect.

Comment: @self Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in that you are trying to test `test_func()` and thought of a possible solution. I think there are better testing approaches than what you have in mind, which is what I'm trying to get at with my previous comment.

Comment: @self Also, your example code probably to simplifies the situation too much. Take some time to figure out a more complete example that includes enough to illustrate the complexities of the problem you are trying to solve, but doesn't include unnecessary details. Check out [mcve] for some suggestions on how to create such an example.